# SQL Server trigger dependent on change of varbinary column to track changes

Tags: sql-server

I want to track changes on a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column in SQL Server.
Goal is to store the date, user and the old `VARBINARY` value for each update into a separate table.

My code for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_ChangeTrackingPictures 
ON dbo.tbl_Content 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT dbo.tbl_PictureHistory (OldPicture, ChangedBy, ChangeDate, SourceID)
        SELECT
            D.Picture, 
            CURRENT_USER, 
            GETDATE(), 
            D.ID
        FROM
            DELETED D 
        JOIN 
            INSERTED I ON D.ID = I.ID
        WHERE
            HASHBYTES ('MD5', D.Picture) <> HASHBYTES ('MD5', I.Picture)
```

With this I always get a server timeout error when I update the column.

It works if I leave out

```
WHERE
    HASHBYTES ('MD5', D.Picture) <> HASHBYTES ('MD5', I.Picture)
```

But this would track every update of the row even if the `VARBINARY` itself was not touched.

I also tried the simple

```
WHERE
    D.Picture <> I.Picture
```

with the same result.

Comment: wrap the code with `if update(picture) begin...end`

Comment: Every edition of SQL Server supports temporal tables which will give you a complete history with (practically) zero work. Is there a reason you're preferring to build this yourself?